# No puedo cambiar la versión de mi Java

Tags: java, windows

He configurado la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME apuntando a la carpeta de mi Open jdk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de verificar en la consola CMD la versión de mi Java, me sigue apareciendo la version del jdk 1.8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso para tener el Open JDK por defecto?

Esto es lo que aparece cuando imprimo mi variable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado al colocar el path en consola:

> PATH=D:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;D:\VBRYANDC\Programas\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;D:\VBRYANDC\WS_SpringBoot\Instaladores\spring-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\bin;%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm;;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin

Comment: imprime tu variable path y ponla en la pregunta, seguro allí esta le problema

Comment: @RuslanLópez acabo de añadirlo

Comment: pusiste java_home no path, ahora pon path, y ponlo como texto, no todos pueden ver tus imágens

Comment: @RuslanLópez obtengo este resultado

Comment: @RuslanLópez revisar el post acab ode añadir el resultado

Comment: ahora pon el resultado de los comandos, where javac y where java

Comment: @RuslanLópez este es el resultado:
C:\Users\USER>where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\USER>where javac
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac.exe

Comment: Si instalaste el Oracle Java usando un MSI, trata reiniciando y/o corriendo algo como Ccleaner, pues van a quedar cosas en el registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que pude notar:

- La Variable JAVA_HOME no está en tu PATH. así que es irrelevante para el problema
- por tu salida de `where java`, se ve que estas usndo un java que venia para herramientas de Oracle y que se ubica en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`

Lo primero que debes de hacer es retirar `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` de tu PATH.

Con ello debería de reconocerte el programa `java.exe` ubicado en `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin`.

La forma más elegante es mandar esas rutas a otras variables, como es el caso de JAVA_HOME, así que si eres quisquilloso lo mejor es remover de tu PATH las dos referencias a `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` y agregar una a `JAVA_HOME/bin`, de esa manera podrías cambiar rápidamente tu JDK sin tener que buscar la parte exacta en tu variable PATH.

Si eres todavía más fánático del órden podrías adicionalmente remplazar `C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\bin` por `MVN_HOME\bin` con tu respectiva nueva variable MVN_HOME (Algunos prefieren MAVEN_HOME).

Comment: Retire del path C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath pero aun me sigue apareciendo el jdk 1.8 por defecto al ejecutar el comando java -version

Comment: en el caso de windows... debes cerrar el dialgo de variables de sistema y la terminal para ver si surtió cambios, puedes veificr corriendo de nuevo `where java` en una nueva terminal después de eso

Comment: este es el resultado
C:\Users\USER>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\USER>java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: sorpresa... algún novato te metió java.exe dentro de la carpeta de sistema, bórrala de allí, no es su lugar porque no es un programa de sistema

Comment: Gracias !!! ese era el problema ya esta con la version del Open jdk 11 :)

Comment: Bien, ahora para puntuar en este sitio, si la respuesta te fue útil le das flechita arriba, si resolvió tu probema le das en la palomita ( y así la gente hallá las respuestas útiles más rápido ). Por lo demás te dejo el link del [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).