# Cambiar versión de Java para poder ejecutar eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, windows10, configuración

Hace unos días se actualizó una versión nueva de Java, cuando he ido a abrir el IDE Eclipse me ponía el siguiente error:

> "A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must
>   be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was
>   found after searching the following locations: C:/Program
>   File/Java/jre1.8.0_241/bin".

No puedo abrir eclipse por lo que tampoco puedo cambiar la ruta al nuevo Java. He probado a cambiar las variables de entorno pero sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema. 
Un saludo.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar, basicamente que entre en el archivo eclipse.ini y verifiques las rutas hay, y mira si todas existen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129024/error-java-runtime-environment-jre-or-java-development-kit-must-be-available

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas configurar la variabe de JAVA_HOME al jdk 17 o superior que tengas instalado y la variable path al JAVA_home /bin  en el link te explica. Es posible que tu variable path tenga una ruta a oracle, puedes subir la variable de jdk/bin antes de la de oracle y con eso ya abre tu eclipse
[No puedo cambiar la versión de mi Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282958/no-puedo-cambiar-la-versi%C3%B3n-de-mi-java)